# Get data from JSON string, foreach, more than one of the same type

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a JSON object I'm trying to parse through and grab data. It starts off as:

```json
"id": "5019b4b40cd8a056446b8eb4",
"checkItemStates": [
  {
    "idCheckItem": "xxxxxxxx",
    "state": "complete"
  }, {
    "idCheckItem": "xxxxxxxx",
    "state": "complete"
  }
],
```

..........etc for about 20 more lines.

Now what I want to get at is:

```json
"member": {
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXc",
  "avatarHash": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "fullName": 
}
```

I want to get at that fullName but there maybe more than one member, there might be 20 members, or just 2. I will have no idea from object to object and there maybe 100's of objects.

How do I

1. basically pull a foreach on a group of JSON objects
2. extract member.fullName from each object that may have an amount more one members?

Comment: Where does the data come from? Can you change how the data is organized? Are the different members defined in an array?

Answer (score 5):

First you pass your JSON string ([there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)) to [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which gives you a javascript object.

Then you access properties of that javascript object through dot notation or bracket notation.

Example:

```
// white space added for readability - not legal syntax (see fiddle)
var jsonString = "{\"member\": {
    \"id\": \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXc\",
    \"avatarHash\": \"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",
    \"fullName\": \"Bob Dole\"}
}";

var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// dot notation
alert(parsed.member.fullName); // Bob Dole

// bracket notation
alert(parsed['member']['fullName']); // Bob Dole
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ga5Fq/

Comment: As I stated above there will be more than just one member.fullName.  This 'string' is anywhere from 20 to 50 lines long with multiple brackets, comma separated.  It's not as simple as getting one name through the dot notation.  There might be 5 member.names (all different) that I need to pull.

Comment: @Verber having multiple properties with the same name is not valid JSON, so i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: this is from a Trello card (which is just a productivity tool in case your not familiar).  On each card 5 people might have worked on it so I might see "CardUpdated.....member.fullname" different times.  So I"m wondering if there is a foreach I could use for json.

Comment: @Verber you would pass the JSON to JSON.parse and then you can loop over it however you like - it's just a javascript object.